# Update Google sheet Every 1hr

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can I make this script run and update the google sheet every 1hr. I want new data to append at the bottom not to overwrite the existing data and is there any possibility it will delete the duplicate data automatically on the basis of Column C, deleting old values and leaves new.

```
function youTubeSearchResults() {
  // 1. Retrieve values from column "A".
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().filter(([a]) => a);

  // 2. Retrieve your current values.
  const modifyResults = values.flatMap(([keywords]) => {
    const searchResults = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/search?part=snippet&q=${keywords}&maxResults=10&type=video&order=viewCount&videoDuration=short&publishedAfter=2022-09-27T00:00:00Z`).getContentText());
    
    const fSearchResults = searchResults.items.filter(function (sr) { return sr.id.kind === "youtube#video" });
    return fSearchResults.map(function (sr) { return [keywords, sr.id.videoId, `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${sr.id.videoId}`, sr.snippet.title, sr.snippet.publishedAt, sr.snippet.channelTitle, sr.snippet.channelId, `https://www.youtube.com/channel/${sr.snippet.channelId}`, sr.snippet.thumbnails.high.url] });
  });

  // 3. Retrieve viewCounts and subscriberCounts.
  const { videoIds, channelIds } = modifyResults.reduce((o, r) => {
    o.videoIds.push(r[1]);
    o.channelIds.push(r[6]);
    return o;
  }, { videoIds: [], channelIds: [] });
  const limit = 50;
  const { viewCounts, subscriberCounts } = [...Array(Math.ceil(videoIds.length / limit))].reduce((obj, _) => {
    const vIds = videoIds.splice(0, limit);
    const cIds = channelIds.splice(0, limit);
    const res1 = YouTube.Videos.list(["statistics"], { id: vIds, maxResults: limit }).items.map(({ statistics: { viewCount } }) => viewCount);
    const obj2 = YouTube.Channels.list(["statistics"], { id: cIds, maxResults: limit }).items.reduce((o, { id, statistics: { subscriberCount } }) => (o[id] = subscriberCount, o), {});
    const res2 = cIds.map(e => obj2[e] || null);
    obj.viewCounts = [...obj.viewCounts, ...res1];
    obj.subscriberCounts = [...obj.subscriberCounts, ...res2];
    return obj;
  }, { viewCounts: [], subscriberCounts: [] });
  const ar = [viewCounts, subscriberCounts];
  const rr = ar[0].map((_, c) => ar.map(r => r[c]));

  // 4. Merge data.
  const res = modifyResults.map((r, i) => [...r, ...rr[i]]);

  // 5. Put values on Spreadsheet.
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hourly Trigger youTubeSearchResults

```
function hourlytrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "youTubeSearchResults").length==0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("youTubeSearchResults").timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  }
}
```

To append data:

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, I don't know where to put this code on existing script but when i put it on top of the existing script it gives me that error. `12:45:24 AM Error 
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for ScriptApp.Trigger.getHandlerFunction.
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:2
hourlytrigger @ Code.gs:2`

Comment: I had a string misplaced.  It's a standalone function for creating a timebased trigger for your function named "youTubeSearchResults".  It helps you to prevent creating multiple triggers which can be difficult to debug.

Comment: it's mean i have to use it in a blank sheet.  sorry cooper i have no programming background so if you explain me in detail it will be a great help for me.

Comment: I don't understand when you say "I have to use it in a blank sheet".  But maybe you're asking where to save it? Anywhere in a gs file.  I would put it in the file where you have the handlerfunction.

Comment: Thanks Cooper here is the link of my sheet [Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ewci4Sd1BxWhJ18vKvDst-P833ULQpSNstGBkpH_MFQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What do you wish me to do?

Comment: cooper sorry to bug you but when i use the code like the `function hourlytrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "youTubeSearchResults").length==0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("youTubeSearchResults").timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  }
}

function youTubeSearchResults() {
  // 1. Retrieve values from column "A".
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().filter(([a]) => a);
` it wont generate any results

Comment: I am sorry but your question was how to run the function every hour.  That's what the trigger does.

Comment: This runs: `function youTubeSearchResults() {   
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();   
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().filter(([a]) => a);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}` and produces output

Comment: I can see its creating a trigger but problem is when I make a test run it is not generating any results on the sheet.

Comment: That is because you did not put any results on the sheet

Comment: you can see in the sheet I have results and now when I run the hourly trigger from function by my self for a new keyword it won't generate any data.

Comment: Did you wait and hour yet?

Comment: sorry cooper maybe it won't run in real time but now I can see it updated the fields in my sheet for new keywords, my last question, is it going to append new data in the sheet or overwrite the old data.

Comment: You should know that from how you wrote your code.  If you wrote it to over write then it will over write.  If you wrote to append then it will append.

Comment: It looks like you are going to overwrite it

Comment: actually someone help me to achieve this as I told you I have very less programming background experience and i believe it will overwrite but  Thanks for your support I will make a new question about appending data or maybe you can see it and help me here.

Comment: I added the append code

Comment: Thank you so much Cooper for your patience with a noob like me. Cooper one last thing, I wonder if you can help me to solve that too. when I run the script with more then 100 keywords it gives me that error `TypeError: rr[i] is not iterable
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:42
youTubeSearchResults @ Code.gs:42` code written for that line is `// 4. Merge data.
  const res = modifyResults.map((r, i) => [...r, ...rr[i]]);`